# jQuery: need I an "each" for every "click" item?

Tags: javascript, jquery

having

```js
/* 1 */
$("div").click(function(e) {
  alert(".click() called on '" + e.currentTarget.id + "'");
});

/* 2 
$("div").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(e) {
      alert(".click() called on '" + e.currentTarget.id + "'");
    });
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target 1">
  The Target One
</div>
<div id="other 2">
  The Target TWO
</div>
```

What is the difference between the two functions `1` and `2`, knowing that the result is the same?!...

Comment: No difference other than less clarity and doing something manually jQuery can do for you.

Comment: There is no difference. Each in example 2 is redundant

Comment: So I can write the first version without functional restrictions/differences vs the second

Comment: if you have a lot of divs, the second one is probably slower...

Comment: need to realize that jQuery will use `each` internally....that's how instances get isolated and why you can do the same thing to all matching elements in selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your use case of simply attaching an event handler to a bunch of elements, there is no difference between both of your solutions.

Here is a bit more detail for the two approaches:

JQuery's `each` is the equivalent to [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). It gives you the option to iterate over every element of the array (or more generally spoken -  collection). Usually it is used to execute a context sensitive function (doing specific things with different elements of the input collection). In your example 2 you could insert an `if` clause to exclude certain `div` elements from receiving an click handler or do additional stuff, that's not supposed to go inside the event handler.

Option 1 is the straightforward approach for attaching event handlers. Since in native javascript you have no option to target several elements at once (which however is a very common usecase) you "manually" have to iterate over your collection of HTML elements. This however is(was) not the easiest task, since the returned [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) did not use to have an easy way to iterate over it's elements*. A common way in vanilla js was to borrow the iteration function from the Array prototype and create such a monster:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("element"),
    function(element){element.addEventListener("type",
       function(){/* code */}
    )}
);
```

jQuery made this easy by simply accepting a collection of elements and in the background it then iterates over the collection and attaches the event handler to every single element.

```
$("element").on("type(s)",function(){/* code */})
```

or even easier

```
$("element").<type>(function(){/* code */})
```

`*` an interator function has been added for NodeLists  not too long ago and still does not have global support.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. That is what i was looking for ! :)

Comment: I did not look into the code, so I cannot be 100% certain, but I would say the difference in negligible. In both cases you iterate once over your input collection, just the order is slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that jQuery [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function gives you access to the *index* of the element being iterated over and lets you execute a function, but in your case there is no functional difference so you should use the first version whose syntax is easier to write/read.